# How to implement master-master replication in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, replication, multi-master, master-master-replication

I am working on a project which requires my database client to scale horizontally for higher availability but it is required to use RDBMS for our solution. Therefore, we want to implement master-master replication for PostgreSQl.

My concern is the usage of paid licensed plugins as we want to refrain from using it. We wish to implement it ourselves for extra credit but if there is any open source plugins we are open to it.

Next concern will be to be aware of the best practices to implement it. It'd be nice to know else self exploration will be the key.

Comment: You don't need multi-master for high-availability.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name If my master server fails I want my replicated master to finish the job since I cannot grant the standby server that privilege.

Comment: There is no free (or open source) master-master replication solution for current Postgres versions. You will either need to build your own, or use the paid solution from 2ndQuadrant

Comment: Can you suggest me articles or blogs where I can learn to build one on my own ?

Comment: you can do Hot Standby using wal-shipping  its a master to slave setup and tools like pgpool can off read only to the slave,  https://www.pgpool.net/docs/pgpool-II-3.6.8/en/html/runtime-config-load-balancing.html     Master to Master setups are extremely difficult to get correct

Comment: Don't go that way - it is painful and full of conceptual problems. Use a simple failover cluster like Patroni and be happy.

Comment: How many concurrent sessions do you expect? My advice: use a simple master-slave setup. Structure your code so that if/when a failover happens the code reconnects and tries again.

Comment: I am expecting network packets to be exchanged and I am sure to use bidirectional replication method. I don't think that master-slave replication will be the approach we want to pursue.